# How to get original positions of listview items after filtering?

Tags: android, listview, search

This is probably going to get marked as a duplicate, but I've scoured every single post related to my problem on here and none of them fixed it, so I'm making my own post to see if someone can specifically help me.

The problem I have is that when I search for something in my listview, the position is messed up. So if I have a listview AA, BB, CC, AB, and I search for A, it will return AA, AB like it's supposed to, but if I click on AB, it will give me BB, since AB is now in position 1 instead of 3. How can I get the original positions of my data for my onclick listener? Thanks.

Here is my custom listview class:

```
public class CustomListViewClass {

// Store the id of the  movie poster
private String mEquation;
// Store the name of the movie
public String mName;
public int previousPosition;

// Constructor that is used to create an instance of the CustomListViewClass object
public CustomListViewClass(String mName, String mEquation) {
    this.mEquation = mEquation;
    this.mName = mName;
}

public String getmEquation() {
    return mEquation;
}

public void setmEquation(String mEquation) {
    this.mEquation = mEquation;
}

public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setmName(String mName) {
    this.mName = mName;
}

}
```

My custom listview adapter:

```
public class CustomListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomListViewClass> implements Filterable  {

//Define list items
TextView textView;
TextView formula_two;

//Define list
private Context mContext;
private List<CustomListViewClass> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<CustomListViewClass> moviesListFiltered = new ArrayList<>();

private int layoutResource;

public CustomListviewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes ArrayList<CustomListViewClass> list) {
    super(context, 0 , list);
    mContext = context;
    moviesList = list;
    moviesListFiltered = list;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

    CustomListViewClass currentMovie = moviesListFiltered.get(position);

    textView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(currentMovie.getmName());
    TextView equation = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.formula_one);
    equation.setText(currentMovie.getmEquation());

    return listItem;
}

int previousPosition;

public int getPreviousPosition() {
    return previousPosition;
}


public void setPreviousPosition(int previousPosition) {
    this.previousPosition = previousPosition;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return moviesListFiltered.size();
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                results.count = moviesList.size();
                results.values = moviesList;
            } else {//do the search
                List<CustomListViewClass> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                for (CustomListViewClass o : moviesListFiltered)
                    if (o.mName.toUpperCase().startsWith(searchStr)) resultsData.add(o);
                results.count = resultsData.size();
                results.values = resultsData;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            moviesListFiltered = (ArrayList<CustomListViewClass>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
}
```

And my main **fragment**

```
public class MainEquations extends ListFragment {

private ListView listView; //Main listview
private CustomListviewAdapter mAdapter; //Custom adapter for listview
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
public static final String TAG = MainEquations.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_equations, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //Find listview in xml
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<CustomListViewClass> equationsList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Populate listview with items
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Ampere's Law" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Angular Acceleration" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Angular Velocity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Belt Velocity" , "V = (πdₘnₘ)/12"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Bolt Stress Area" , "A = π/4(dₙ - 0.9743/n)²"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Brake Clamp Load" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Buoyant Force" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Conductivity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Coulomb's Law" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Darcy's Law" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Density" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Drag Force" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Dynamic Viscosity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Elastic Potential Energy" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Electric Field" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Engineering Strain" , "ε = ΔL/L₀"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Engineering Stress" , "σ = F/A₀"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Escape Velocity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Flow Head Loss" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Fluid Pressure" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Fluid Surface Tension" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Force" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Fracture Toughness" , "Kᵢc = Yσ⋅Sqrt(πa)"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Gauss Law" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Gibb's Free Energy" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Gravitational Force" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Gravitational Potential Energy" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Horsepower using Belt Velocity/Force" , "HP = (Fb⋅Vb)/33000"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Ideal Gas Law" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Induced Voltage" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Kinematic Viscosity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Kinetic Energy" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Mach Number" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Magnetic Force Charge" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Moment" , "F⋅d"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Momentum" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Nernst Equation" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Ohms Law" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Open Channel Water Flow" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Orbital Velocity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Orifice Discharge" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Pump Power" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Refraction" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Resistivity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Resonant Frequency" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Reynolds Number" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Rotational Kinetic Energy" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Shear Modulus" , "G = τ/γ"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Shear Strain" , "γ = τ/G"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Shear Stress" , "τ = F/A"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Shear Stress of Linear Helical Spring" , "τ = Kₛ(8FD/πd³)"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Surface Charge Density" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Thermal Deformation" , "δₜ = αL(T - T₀)"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Torque" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Velocity" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Voltage Divider" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Voltage Drop" , "Placeholder"));
    equationsList.add(new CustomListViewClass( "Young's Modulus" , "E = σ/ε"));



    mAdapter = new CustomListviewAdapter(getActivity(),equationsList);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Set onClick functions for listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {

            switch(position) {
                case 15:
                setVariables("Engineering Strain",
                        "<center>$$\\epsilon = \\frac{\\Delta L}{L_0}$$</center>",
                        "\\(Unitless\\)",
                        "\\(\\Delta L = \\mathrm{change~in~length~in~}in, mm\\)",
                        "\\(L_0 = \\mathrm{original~area~in~}in, mm\\)");
                break;
                case 16:
                setVariables("Engineering Stress",
                        "<center>$$\\sigma = \\frac{F}{A_0}$$</center>",
                        "\\(Pa, MPa, psi, kpsi\\)",
                        "\\(F = \\mathrm{axial~force~in~}N, kip\\)",
                        "\\(A_0 = \\mathrm{cross~sectional~area~in~} m^2, ft^2\\)");
                break;
                case 2:
                setVariables("Moment",
                        "<center>$$M= F{\\cdot}d$$</center>",
                        "\\(lb{\\cdot}ft, N{\\cdot}m\\)",
                        "\\(F = \\mathrm{force~in~}N, lb\\)",
                        "\\(d = \\mathrm{distance~of~radial~arm~in~} m, ft\\)");
                break;
                case 3:
                setVariables("Shear Stress",
                        "<center>$$\\epsilon = \\frac{\\Delta L}{L_0}$$</center>",
                        "\\(Unitless\\)",
                        "\\(\\Delta L = \\mathrm{change~in~length~in~}in, mm\\)",
                        "\\(L_0 = \\mathrm{original~area~in~}in, mm\\)");
                break;

            }
        }
    });

    return view;

}

public void setVariables(String title, String equation, String units, String variable_one, String variable_two) {
    Bundle info = new Bundle();
    info.putString("KEY_TITLE", title);
    info.putString("KEY_EQUATION", equation);
    info.putString("KEY_UNITS", units);
    info.putString("KEY_VARIABLES_ONE", variable_one);
    info.putString("KEY_VARIABLES_TWO", variable_two);
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    CustomEquationsDialog dialog = new CustomEquationsDialog();
    dialog.setArguments(info);
    dialog.show(fm, TAG);
}

//Alert function for dialog
public void alert (String title, String message) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Stuff
}

//Options menu created
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_equations, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

    final SearchView searchView2 = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.item_search).getActionView();

    searchView2.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView2.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    searchView2.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Filter filter = mAdapter.getFilter();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                listView.clearTextFilter();
                filter.filter(newText);
            } else {
                filter.filter(newText);
                listView.setFilterText(newText);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchView2.clearFocus(); //Close searchview when enter button pressed
            return true;
        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one replace below two methods

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

        CustomListViewClass currentMovie = moviesList.get(position);

        textView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(currentMovie.getmName());
        TextView equation = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.formula_one);
        equation.setText(currentMovie.getmEquation());

        return listItem;
    }
```

and your filter should be like below

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                    moviesList = moviesListFiltered;
                } else {//do the search
                    List<CustomListViewClass> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                    for (CustomListViewClass o : moviesListFiltered)
                        if (o.mName.toUpperCase().startsWith(searchStr)) resultsData.add(o);
                    moviesList = resultsData;
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                moviesList = (ArrayList<CustomListViewClass>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting a null pointer exception when I click on the search button in the toolbar now.


 NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

It says the problem is CustomListViewClass currentMovie = moviesList.get(position); is returning null

Comment: have you check `moviesList`  in constructor ?

Comment: `private List<CustomListViewClass> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();` is how it's defined, but I don't know how to make it not null when  calling .get(position)

Comment: you have to put debug at constructor before bind list in adapter and you have to check that you got data in constructor in moviesList.